# why my react simple timer project doesn't work?

Tags: reactjs, tsx

I'm trying to code a simple timer with two buttons.
Start Button: timer will be added by one every 10ms.
Lap Button: timer will be pushed to an array and also showed in a pre tag.
Unfortunately, Lap Button doesn't work.
can anybody help me figure this issue out?
TY.

```
import { useState } from "react";
import { formatSeconds } from "./format";
let interval : NodeJS.Timer;

function App() {
  const [buttonName, setButtonName] = useState("Start");
  let [timer, setTimer] = useState(0);
  const laps : Array<number> = [];

  const handleStartClick = () => {
    setButtonName(buttonName === "Start" ? "Stop" : "Start")

    if(buttonName === "Start"){
      interval = setInterval(() => {
        setTimer(timer += 1)
      }, 10);
    }else{
      clearInterval(interval)
    }
    
  }

  const handleLapClick = () => {
    laps.push(timer);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={handleStartClick}>{buttonName}</button>
      <button onClick={handleLapClick}>Lap</button>
      <div>
        <p>Elapsed:</p> <pre id="elapsed">{formatSeconds(timer)}</pre>
      </div>
      <hr />
      <div id="laps">
        <p>Laps:</p>
        {laps?.map((item) => {
          return <pre key={item}>{formatSeconds(item)}</pre>;
        })}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Problem:***: Your component is not updating on `handleLapClick` function.

***Solution:***

- Change `laps` to a `state` variable using the `useState hook`
- Instead of pushing values to the `laps array`, update the `laps state` by creating a `new array` that includes the current timer value.

(The reason behind creating a new array and then updating the laps state is because of a concept called, [state immutability](https://reacttraining.com/blog/state-in-react-is-immutable) in React)

***Changes to be made:***

```
const [laps, setLaps] = useState<number[]>([]);
```

```
const handleLapClick = () => {
    setLaps((prevLaps) => [...prevLaps, timer]);
  };
```

***Correct code after making changes:***

```
import { useState } from "react";
import { formatSeconds } from "./format";

let interval: NodeJS.Timer;

function App() {
  const [buttonName, setButtonName] = useState("Start");
  const [timer, setTimer] = useState(0);
  const [laps, setLaps] = useState<number[]>([]);

  const handleStartClick = () => {
    setButtonName((prevButtonName) =>
      prevButtonName === "Start" ? "Stop" : "Start"
    );

    if (buttonName === "Start") {
      interval = setInterval(() => {
        setTimer((prevTimer) => prevTimer + 1);
      }, 10);
    } else {
      clearInterval(interval);
    }
  };

  const handleLapClick = () => {
    setLaps((prevLaps) => [...prevLaps, timer]);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={handleStartClick}>{buttonName}</button>
      <button onClick={handleLapClick}>Lap</button>
      <div>
        <p>Elapsed:</p> <pre id="elapsed">{formatSeconds(timer)}</pre>
      </div>
      <hr />
      <div id="laps">
        <p>Laps:</p>
        {laps.map((item, index) => (
          <pre key={index}>{formatSeconds(item)}</pre>
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```